# 6 month baby. Breast to bottle

Tags: breastfeeding, bottle-feeding

I am struggling to transition from breast to bottle. He just won't take the bottle. I've tried different flows, different bottles, and given him to different people for feeding. Nothing seems to work. Also, it seems like the breast milk isn’t filling him up. He is asking for it 7 times a night and then waking up very soon after each feed. He eats one bowl of Cerelac and rice each in the morning and afternoon but he is still wanting milk. The very few times he has taken the bottle he will sleep perfectly for 2 solid hours. HELP!

Comment: Welcome! Can you please specify what exactly you are asking about? You are listening many aspects that may or may not be related. Is it about a feeding method (breast vs. bottle), milk (breast milk vs. formula), satiation, sleeping through the night… Please take the [tour] and browse through the [help], especially [ask], then [edit] your post so that the community can better understand what exactly you are asking about and help in a meaningful way.

Comment: We found that temperature plays a big role. The bottle in our case was not warm enough. Making it just a little warmer made a huge difference.

Comment: You might want to get a lactation consultant. It's possible that he gets a bad latch or doesn't suckle well, which would explain why he doesn't eat enough to stay fuller longer at any given feeding.

Comment: Would it be breastmilk (i.e., same taste but different medium) in the bottle? Or formula? Answers may differ depending on what you are feeding.

Answer (score 1):

Give it time.

Our kids all moved from breast at different times. They all did move when they were ready, not something you will find on a calendar...

One of them did breast and bottle in parallel, but he did want to eat a lot.

All 3 were high on the growth chart so they were always hungry (still are - they eat well).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear that he's having a rough time.

The good news is, he takes cereal.

Would it work to mix the formula with cereal so it's a watery soup and then spoon-feed him?

I'm not suggesting you give up entirely on getting him to drink the bottle, but it might help him in the in-between period.

You might also want to post your question on https://www.whattoexpect.com.

They have a huge community with a LOT of combined experience between all the mommy members.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check into the issue of "excess lipase". It can cause the milk to taste bad unless you follow a certain procedure after pumping.